# Dynamic set operations in compilation phase

Tags: gams-math

I am trying to define some sets dynamically with set operations (in my case the "-" operation). However, the "-" operation seems to apply only during the execution phase, and when using this set when defining other sets, gams fails with the following error: **644  set.ident or #.ident has undefined data**. I believe the issue is that the set defined with the minus operation does not get created until the execution phase.

I could not find a solution to create the set during the compilation phase. Any help appreciated, with a minimal reproducible example below.

```
set alphabet /
"a"
"b"
"c"
/;

set a(alphabet) /
"a"
/;

sets bc(alphabet);
bc(alphabet) = alphabet(alphabet) - a(alphabet);

set test1(alphabet)
/
#a
/;

set test2(alphabet)
/
#a
#bc
/;

set test3(alphabet)
/
set.a
/;

set test4(alphabet)
/
set.a
set.bc
/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, "bc(alphabet) = alphabet(alphabet) - a(alphabet);" is an execution time statement. Doing a set subtraction at compile time in GAMS directly, is not so easy (in contrast to a set addition, which works). But if you use a recent GAMS system (24.9), you could use the new  [embedded code facility](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_EmbeddedCode.html) to do this:

```
set alphabet /
"a"
"b"
"c"
/;

set a(alphabet) /
"a"
/;

sets bc(alphabet);

$onEmbeddedCode Python:
  gams.set("bc", list(set(gams.get("alphabet")) - set(gams.get("a"))))
$offEmbeddedCode bc
```

I hope that helps!
Lutz

Comment: thanks for the tip, although seems a bit overkill to use python just to do this... should be a feature in gams